# Append chart object to html div

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, c3.js

I am new to C3 js and trying to get this prototype to work. I have a json file and this has a the chart specifications for 3 charts. I want to read this json object and then create a div for each row, assign it the ID thats CHART_ID in the row and then append the chart to this div.The chart meta data is included in the file in each row, the goal is to dynamically generate  chart with its metadata. By doing an ng-repeat for the fileData object I am able to dynamically create the divs. However it never renders the chart on screen. you can even see the chart object  on the line

```
var chart = eval(chartFunction);
```

if you put a breakpoint there, you see the c3 generated chart object but when i try to append this to the html element for the chart

```
var chartElement = angular.element(document.getElementById(chartId));     
chartElement.append(chart.element);
```

this doesnt show anything. If you try the following instead of ng-repeat this is able to load each chart into its div

```
<div id="cht1"></div>
<div id="cht2"></div>
<div id="cht3"></div>
```

But instead of hardcoding the div elements I would like to create as many divs as the no of rows in my fileData object. 
 Can someone please show me what im missing here and how to correctly append the respective Div to its chart object going through the loop with ng-repeat. Your help is really appreciated. Please look at the plunker below to see the example

http://plnkr.co/edit/KCUslUxqBhYiOFZGx1gG?p=preview

Comment: Never ever use eval()! You are sending JavaScript code as a string via Ajax? The way to go would be to request only the data and no code from the back-end via ajax. An example is here: http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html And your actual question I do not quite understand. Could you explain what you want achieve with append? To append the chart to a HTML element you need to use the c3 config property bindto.

Comment: Yes, try and find another way other then using eval.  Also a couple of things with your example shouldn't the ng-repeat be inside the div with the ng-controller?  Also it would be better to be using ng-attr-id to set the id of the new div.

Comment: Thanks @ssc-hrep3 and Craig. I have updated the plunker and reworded my question. You should be able to see the three divs created but for some reason appending the chart element to the div in angular is not creating the chart. If you manually put three divs with those ids in the html it works. How can i do this with ng-repeat as shown in the plunker.  and the bindto property already exists in the chart meta data and is assigned to the div. The eval is just for trying this functionality out. What would be the recommended way to convert the javascript function from string to a function?

Comment: This would be a better way then using eval: [http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/](http://www.sitepoint.com/call-javascript-function-string-without-using-eval/).

Comment: Thanks @craig, will change it in my app, any idea about why angular is not able to get the dynamically created div though? i have tried angular.document.getElementById, angular.element(document.querySelector(chartId) but it still doesnt work. not sure why it cant find the created div? but if the div is hardcoded then works?!?

Comment: If this is still a problem maybe you should consider using a directive for this instead?